# How can I add a context menu item in windows 7 that could backup the selected files as zip?

Tags: windows-7, backup, zip, context-menu

I need to add a context menu item, which will open WinRAR with some args/flags and pass the filenames of those which are selected to it too.

For instance, softwares like WinRAR accepts command-line arguments where we could specify file format, save folder, compression level etc.

I've noticed the shell and shellex registry pattern in windows and after playing around for a while, I've successfully added a **"Open with my app"** for a particular extension.

But for multiple files selection (of various types), menu items under `* key` points to something else! I couldn't understand what they were! My humble intentions comprises of making a backup file (backup.zip) from whichever files or folders that are selected and save them to a custom `my_backup` folder.

Comment: I'm new to this site. Could someone explain to me what these down votings are for? Did I mess up any community guidelines?

Comment: Doesn't your archive manager support context menu options?

Comment: I think the downvotes are because any decent archive manager will have context menu support.

Answer (score 1):

WinRAR already has this feature. It's here in the settings, under "Shell integration":

[image]